# Wordpress Custom API GET request from External App with XML Parameter

Tags: php, api, wp-api, xml

I am new to WordPress API's and API's in general. I have an external app that is sending a GET request to my WordPress site with an XML string as the only parameter. I created a custom API that responds back with it's own XML string. I am successfully sending my XML string to the app and the app is displaying the data correctly. The problem is that I have to first get the XML string coming from the GET request from the app and extract some information that I then have to add to my XML string, such as a ConversationID. I have no idea how to do this and I have searched everywhere on the web for information on this, but have not found anything yet. Here is my custom API PHP code in WordPress:

```
function my_awesome_func( WP_REST_Request $request ) {
    
    $menu = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?><UssdMessage><MessageType></MessageType><ConversationID>42B29890-4404-4E26-B1AD-7C487C9F373F</ConversationID><SessionID>0000000159CB2EFC00</SessionID><TransactionID>2358dfa3-0e3c-40ad-96ce-756cb1d6ae3f</TransactionID><MSISDN></MSISDN><MessageString> +TestCompany%0d%0a%0d%0a+Are+You+At+Work%0d%0a1.+Yes%0d%0a2.+No%0d%0a4.+Leave+Application%0d%0a0.+Exit</MessageString><Success>True</Success><IsFinal>False</IsFinal><DateTimeReceived>06/06/2015 14:50:11</DateTimeReceived><MNO>MTN</MNO></UssdMessage>";
    
    return $menu;
}

add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
  register_rest_route( 'freedom/v1', '/ussd-api', array(
    'methods' => WP_REST_Server::READABLE,
    'callback' => 'my_awesome_func',
  ) );
} );

function maybe_ussd_feed( $served, $result, $request, $server ) {

    if ( '/freedom/v1/ussd-api/' !== $request->get_route() ||
        
        'my_awesome_func' !== $request->get_attributes()['callback'] ) {
        return $served;
    }

    $server->send_header( 'Content-Type', 'text/xml' );
    echo $result->get_data();

    exit;
}
add_filter( 'rest_pre_serve_request', 'maybe_ussd_feed', 10, 4 );
```

I have tried several ideas, but I honestly have no idea what I am doing.